# PHP compute score for equal array values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of values which are sorted in reverse order (highest to lowest value).

I want to award points for each array value, such that lowest value gets 1 point, second lowest 2 points, and so on. If **two or more** values are equal, I sum up all values as if they're not equal and award each value an average of summed values.

Here's an example:

```
Value | Points
 59   |   8
 56   |   7
 55=  |   5,5  (would get 6 if it's not a tie)    
 55=  |   5,5  (would get 5 if it's not a tie)
 54   |   4
 52   |   3
 46   |   2
 19   |   1
```

How can I do this in PHP?

Thanks

Comment: Why 5 to one and 6 to another?

Comment: I computed points with simple `for` loop when there were no ties, but I don't know what to do when we have a tie, so I asked for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you want to store the data or how you want to show it, but here is an example of what you want to achieve:

```
    $arrayPoints = array();
    $array = array(59,56,55,55,55,55,54,52,52,46,19);       
    $numElems = count($array);

    $j = $numElems;     
    for ($i=0; $i<$numElems; $i++)
    {
        $arrayPoints[$array[$i]][] = $j;
        $j--;
    }

    $result = array();
    foreach ($arrayPoints as $pointsInfoKey => $pointsInfoVal)
    {
        $i=0;
        $totalPoints = 0;
        foreach ($pointsInfoVal as $val)
        {
            $totalPoints += $val;
            $i++;
        }
        if ($i!=0) $totalPoints = $totalPoints/$i;

        echo "Value: $pointsInfoKey - Points: $totalPoints \n";
    }
```

The result for this will be:

```
Value: 59 - Points: 11 
Value: 56 - Points: 10 
Value: 55 - Points: 7.5 
Value: 54 - Points: 5 
Value: 52 - Points: 3.5 
Value: 46 - Points: 2 
Value: 19 - Points: 1
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Give an average of all the values against the ties .
suppose there are three enteries for 55 and point against them are 5,6,7
then you can provide each 55 a point of (5+6+7)/3